# How to slice a list with irregular intervals?

Tags: python, numpy

I the following list I want to do slicing such that my final result is [1,1.5,2,2.5,4.5,5] . I tried to access by indices but it gives me error.

```
`list = [1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5]
print(list)
print(list[0,1,2,3,7,8])`
```

Comment: You've tagged this NumPy, but you're not using any NumPy data structures or functionality.

Comment: How is `numpy` involved? You're using plain Python `list`s here (and as a side-note, naming the variable `list` is a terrible idea, as you name shadow the `list` constructor by doing so).

Comment: First I tried this numpy array rather than list that's why I tagged

Comment: for a numpy array, `arr[[0,1,2,3,7,8]]`.  Pay attention to the [].  Index with a list.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a list of indexes to slice or index a list. You have to use a loop—e.g., via a [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), or a function with an implicit loop in it like the one returned by [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> lst = [1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5]
>>> print([lst[i] for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8]])
[1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 4.5, 5]
>>> print(operator.itemgetter(0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8)(lst))
[1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 4.5, 5]
```

---

But you *can* do something like this with numpy arrays. You can't directly use the six indices (because that would mean multidimensional indexing), but you *can* use any array-like, such as a list, containing those six indices:

```
>>> arr = np.array(lst)
>>> print(arr[[0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8]])
[1.  1.5 2.  2.5 4.5 5. ]
```

This is explained in [Index arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays) in the basic indexing tutorial.

Comment: Although due to some [weird backward compatibility logic](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7ccf0e08917d27bc0eba34013c1822b00a66ca6d/numpy/core/src/multiarray/mapping.c#L200) in the NumPy indexing handling, indexing arrays with arbitrary arraylikes can be pretty weird. `a[[1, 2]]` is treated like `a[array([1, 2])]`, but `a[[[1, 2], [3, 4]]]` is treated like `a[array([1, 2]), array([3, 4])]` rather than `a[array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])]`.

Comment: @user2357112 That's because a tuple is not an array-like for index array purposes. That's mentioned in the first sentence of the tutorial section, with a "I'll explain later" link to the end of the same chapter. It's not about backward compatibility; it's because tuples are already used for multidimensional indexing, so it would be ambiguous to also use them for index array indexing.

Comment: No, you're thinking of a different effect. I'm not talking about the difference between indexing with a tuple or other arraylikes; that's documented. I'm talking about how if `index` is a list, `a[index]` is sometimes treated as `a[array(index)]` and sometimes treated as `a[tuple(index)]`.

Comment: @user2357112 Oh, I see, yeah, the top level of a mutlidimensional list is sometimes treated like a tuple, and the docs just say (somewhere) that you should never rely on that, without saying that you also can't rely on it _not_ happening (as you'd hope).

Answer (score 1):

Python's slicing does not support irregular intervals. You must use a list comprehension.

```
lst = [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5]
indices = (0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8)
slice = [lst[i] for i in indices]

print(slice) # [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 4.5, 5]
```

Also, do not use names such as `list` for your variables as this overshadows builtin functions.

Answer (score 1):

Work the other way around; instead of selecting a non-contiguous range, remove the contiguous range you *don't* want. You just want to get the original `list` minus indices 4-6 (inclusive), so copy your `list`, then `del` the indices you don't need:

```
mylist = [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5]
trimmed = mylist[:]
del trimmed[4:7]
print(trimmed)
```

Alternatively, you could use `operator.itemgetter` to retrieve the specific indices you listed, e.g.:

```
from operator import itemgetter

mylist = [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5]
print(itemgetter(0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8)(mylist))
```

`itemgetter` of multiple values will output a `tuple`, so if that bothers you, you'd have to convert back to `list`, e.g. `print(list(itemgetter(0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8)(mylist)))` (and note, the choice to change your variable name to `mylist` made it possible to access the `list` constructor, which would have been impossible if you named your variable `list`).